# Public const variable or private with a get function, which is preferable?

Tags: c++, object, access-specifier

So I have a variable I often have to call outside the class, I was told that I should do this:

```
class Foo{
    public:
        //stuff
    Type getVariable();
    private:
        Type Variable;
        //stuff
}
```

But why can't I just use:

```
class Foo{
    public:
        //stuff
    const Type variable
    private:
        //stuff
}
```

Comment: Do you want to change the variable in any of the member functions? Then don't make it `const`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can, but don't expect the same results.

In the second case, you can't modify `variable` anymore, not even inside the functions.

They're different things.

Comment: But in terms of "security", it comes down to the same thing? Would this be the only aspect that distinguishes these two?

Comment: @PatronBernard no, **all** aspects distinguish the two. They're completely unrelated.

Comment: @PatronBernard, public vs. private is merely a compile time check. It's not really "security". I could still access the variable and modify it, given sufficient motivation. `const` possibly allows the compiler to move the storage into a read-only memory area, and attempts to modify it would cause an access violation, but this varies wildly by compiler and architecture.